# Can't connect to Azure P2S VPN

Tags: vpn, azure

I am receiving this error: The handle specified is invalid
 (Error 0x80090301)

Log shows another error:
On-Error Event  ErrorCode = -2146893055 ErrorSource = RAS

Certificate is installed. Connection works from another PC.

On both computers I have Windows 10 installed. The only difference is that on PC where VPN works I am using local network (with cable), and on PC where I am receiving error I have Wi-Fi internet connection (it isn't limited somehow).

I have tried to disable Firewall without luck. And I don't have any antivirus software that could block connection.

May be the reason that I have some kind of Network Bridge that connect Wi-Fi with Wi-Fi Adapter

Comment: Please post more details about your issue .

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT Can you give me a hint what else information I can add?

Comment: Hi,@Alexej Sommer . Thanks for your details. You're right , this issue may caused by your Network environment. You'd better to check your WiFi configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just want to close this topic.
VPN works fine on all machines except one with Bridge:

[image]

Thank you @Wayne Yang for validating my thoughts